# How to dynamically change the "S3 object key" in AWS CodePipeline when source is S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to use S3 bucket as source for CodePipeline. We want to save source code version like "1.0.1" or "1.0.2" in S3 bucket each time we trigger Jenkins pipeline dynamically as source which is saved in S3 bucket. But since the "S3 object key" is not dynamic we cant able to build artifact based on version numbers which is generated dynamically by Jenkins. Is there a way to make the "S3 object key" dynamic and take value from Jenkins pipeline when code pipeline is triggered.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible natively but you can do that by writing your own Lambda function. It’d require Lambda as it’s a restriction with CodePipeline that you’ve to specify a fixed object key name while setting up the pipeline.

So, let’s say you’ve 2 pipelines, CircleCI (CCI) & CodePipeline (CP). CCI generates some files and push it to your S3 bucket (S3-A). Now, you want CP to pick up the latest zip file as a source. But since the latest zip file will be having different names (1.0.1 or 1.0.2), you can’t do that dynamically.

So, on that S3 bucket (S3-A), you can have have [S3 event notification trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) enabled with your custom Lambda function. Whenever any new object gets uploaded to that S3 bucket (S3-A), your Lambda function will be triggered, it’ll fetch the latest uploaded object to that S3 bucket (S3-A), zip/unzip that object and push it to an another S3 bucket (S3-B) with some fixed name like `file.zip` with which you’ll configure your CP with as a source. As there’s a new object with `file.zip` in your S3 bucket (S3-B), your CP will be triggered automatically.

PS: You’ll have to write your own Lambda function such that it’ll do all those above operations like zipping/unzipping up the newly uploaded object in S3-A, uploading it to S3-B, etc.