# How to Trigger codepipeline with s3 with dynamic s3 object key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I have a bucket whose objects have commitId as their name. I want to pass these commitID to my codepipeline and utilise those id for slack messages.

I am trying to trigger Codepipeline when a zip file is uploaded to s3, however as I can see in the documents, it can only trigger with a static bucket key. I want to trigger with any file name

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-S3.html
I am dealing with a use case where the uploaded object in s3 will have dynamic object keys.

How to deal with this situation?

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459555/how-to-dynamically-change-the-s3-object-key-in-aws-codepipeline-when-source-is) so I know using s3 with lambda and then trigger pipeline with lambda but this will still not work because I need to pass zip file to codebuild

Comment: Have the Lambda zip the S3 object before copying it.  The answer to the referenced question advises exactly this.

Comment: That does not solve my problem because I want to trigger my codepipeline with different file names when they are uploaded to zip. I don't want to uniform it. the idea Is to pass those names to codepipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Have the Lambda record the ID in `commit_id.txt` and add it to the bundle.

---

I understand you want to execute a pipeline when an arbitrary object, say `a5bf8c1.zip` is added to a S3 path, say `MyPipelineBucket/commits/`.  The pipeline has a S3 source, say `MyPipelineBucket/source.zip`.  Your pipeline executions also require the file name value (`a5bf8c1`).

1. Set up S3 Event Notifications on the bucket. Apply [object key name filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-filtering.html) on the `MyPipelineBucket/commits/` prefix.
2. Set a Lambda Function as the [destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations.html)
3. The Lambda receives the Commit ID in the event notification payload as the triggering file name.  Write it to `commit_id.txt` file.  Using the SDK, get the `MyPipelineBucket/commits/a5bf8c1.zip` bundle from S3.  Add `commit_id.txt` to the bundle.  Put the new bundle to `MyPipelineBucket/source.zip`.  This will trigger an execution.
4. In your pipeline, your CodeBuild commands now have access to the Commit ID.  For instance, you can set the Commit ID as an environment variable:

```bash
COMMIT_ID=$(cat commit_id.txt)
echo COMMIT_ID # -> a5bf8c1
```

Comment: I have a question :- When you say "bundle" what does it actually mean. 
Specifically this statement `Using the SDK, get the MyPipelineBucket/commits/a5bf8c1.zip bundle from S3. Add commit_id.txt to the bundle. Put the new bundle to MyPipelineBucket/source.zip`

Does that mean now source.zip will contain commit_id.txt + a5bf8c1.zip contents?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Code bundle = your "zip" file = source artefact.  Yes, CodePipeline executions would get one extra file in the source artefact.

Comment: There are alternatives.  Instead of including the ID in the source artefact, your Lambda could record the CommitID as a Systems Manager Parameter Store string parameter.  Your pipeline would then `GetParameter` at execution time.

Comment: What would be more effective in your opinion?using lambda and bundle or lambda with ssm?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra  The `commit_id.txt` approach has the advantage of fewer moving parts, but I don't think it matters much one way or the other.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra i am in a similar situation did that work finally? dynamically instructing codepipeline to be triggered at different s3 object keys which are github commit ids?

Comment: @curious I would be happy to answer this. Is it possible to Post it as seperate question. I used a different approach for my use case which involves using s3 metadata.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76490988/can-i-dynamically-instruct-aws-codepipeline-to-be-triggered-at-different-s3-obje