# Can I dynamically instruct aws codepipeline to be triggered at different s3 object keys which are github commit ids?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I'd like to trigger codepipeline from s3 buckets. That means code is pushed in github and through github workflow code is uploaded in a zip file to a specific s3 bucket. From what I saw in AWS codepipeline you need to specify  a static name for the object you upload to the bucket. That is non convenient because an intended behavior is to keep some sort of versioning aligned with the commit hash of your latest branch in order to easily revert back when needed. S3 enables versioning but you cannot force the s3 versioning id to whatever you want, i.e: github commit hash.

Is there a way to upload from github to s3 each time different file names: $commit_hash.zip and aws codepipeline to trigger the same pipeline without explicitly changing s3 object names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to upload from github to s3 each time different file names: $commit_hash.zip and aws codepipeline to trigger the same pipeline without explicitly changing s3 object names?

No. You cannot have dynamic key triggers for codepipeline

But there is workaround. It's true that codepipeline does require a static name for the s3 object to get triggered. But you can keep static name and add user-defined metadata as your commit hash and then do any processing related to this commit hash inside your codepipeline

This is how I achieved using s3 user-defined object metadata.

- Your GitHub will upload an s3 bucket with a static name with commit-hash as its metadata header.
- Enable versioning on your bucket.
- Used Eventbridge rule which triggers the codepipeline whenever an s3 object is created.

example of event pattern ( cdk code snippet )

```
 eventPattern: {
        source: ["aws.s3"],
        detailType: ["Object Created"],
        detail: {
          bucket: {
            name: [bucket-name],
          },
          object: {
            key: ['decided-key'],
          },
        },
      },
```

- Once your pipeline is triggered,  you can use/process this commit hash inside your codebuild using aws cli using the following example.

  ```
  post_build:

    commands:

     - export COMMIT_SHA=`aws s3api head-object --bucket ${BUCKET_NAME} --key ${BUCKET_KEY} | jq  -r '.Metadata.commitsha'`
  ```

Comment: Thanks, is the Eventbridge module needed? Isn't the role of aws codepipeline to be triggered when the s3 object is updated?even with a static name? I assume that each time an object is updated to the specific s3 bucket codepipeline is configured to read its source then codepipeline is triggered.

Comment: from aws tutorial:
To add an Amazon S3 source action in CodePipeline, you choose either to:

Use the CodePipeline console Create pipeline wizard (Create a pipeline (console)) or Edit action page to choose the S3 provider option. The console creates an EventBridge rule and a CloudTrail trail that starts your pipeline when the source changes.

Comment: so it seems CodePipeline in the background creates the EventBridge when you chose s3 as source

Comment: I prefer to create event bridge rule because it's more reliable then and I dont need cloudtrail enabled. Plus there is only limit of 5 trails per account ( not sure) so if pipeline count increases in such case it more better to use enventbridge.

Also with eventbridge rule, I have more control on how and when to trigger codepipeline

Yes its creates in the background but I prefer to define my own which give me more control. You can obviously work with codepipeline default behaviour too.

Comment: ` I assume that each time an object is updated to the specific s3 bucket codepipeline is configured to read its source then codepipeline is triggered.` - Yes codepipeline does read its source. That is how it passes that source as artificact to subsequent stages in to codepipeline

Comment: Feel free to clarify further if you have any doubt. If this answer helped you, can you mark it as an answer so that it helps others in the future

Comment: How do I set the commit hash as metadata when storing the s3 object?I am trying to get it from env var in github action workflow but returns error '          aws s3 cp myzip.zip my-bucket-name --metadata '{"commit":$git_hash}'' where 'git_hash=$(git rev-parse --short "$GITHUB_SHA")'